# How would I get rid of this infinite loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
##
numOfYears = 0
## Ask user for the CPI
cpi = input("Enter the CPI for July 2015: ")
## If they didn't enter a digit, try again
while not cpi.isdigit():
    print("Bad input")
    cpi = input("Enter the CPI for July 2015: ")
## Convert their number to a float
cpi = float(cpi)
while cpi <= (cpi * 2):
    cpi *= 1.025
    numOfYears += 1
## Display how long it will take the CPI to double
print("Consumer prices will double in " + str(numOfYears) + " years.")
```

Is there a way to take the number that the user inputs `cpi` and double it so that `while cpi <= (cpi * 2)` doesn't give me an infinite loop? Also, is there a way to allow the user to input a floating point number so that it doesn't return the `Bad input` error? All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Others have already explained why you get that infinite loop: You compare `cpi` to its *current* value instead of its *original* value. However, there's more:

1. The result of `numOfYears` is independent of `cpi`
2. You do not need a loop at all, just use [logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base)

So you could just change your code to this:

```
from math import ceil, log
numOfYears = ceil(log(2) / log(1.025))
```

This gives you the years until *any* CPI has doubled given the annual rate of change of `1.025`.

---

About your other question:

> Also, is there a way to allow the user to input a floating point number so that it doesn't return the 'Bad input' error?

You should just `try` to convert to float and `break` from the loop as soon as it works.

```
while True:
    try:
        cpi = float(input("Enter the CPI for July 2015: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Bad input")
```

But as I said, for what you are calculating in that script, you do not need that number at all.

Answer (score 2):

You should save the value givent as an input

```
cpi = float(cpi)
target_cpi = cpi * 2
while cpi <= target_cpi:
    cpi *= 1.025
    numOfYears += 1
```